# Convert Date Format

Tags: php

I have created a script through which i retrieve values from a rss feed.
One value is in following date format:

```
Thu, 14 Apr 2011 18:23:19 GMT
```

What i wanted this value to be in following format:

```
April 14, 2011 11:53 PM
```

How can i achieve this?

Please help me on this

Thanks

Pankaj

Comment: Read the PHP manual and search SO before asking. How to reformat a date habe been answered hundreds of times before: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[php]+format+date and the first result on Google would have told how to do that as well: https://encrypted.google.com/search?q=format+date+php

Answer (score 4):

The [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class is handy for this. You can use its [`format()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php) method.

```
$datetime = new DateTime('Thu, 14 Apr 2011 18:23:19 GMT');

echo $datetime->format('F j,Y g:i A');
```

Comment: why do you answer such a blatant duplicate at all?

Comment: @Gordon (a) I am not sure this exact case is a duplicate and (b) I'd rather show people the `DateTime` class than people still using `date()` and `strtotime()` (which everyone else used answering this).

Comment: the question is "How to reformat a Date" for which there is more than enough duplicates that show how to use date/strtotime as well as DateTime. Even for the slim possibility that there isnt an exact duplicate for the format the OP asks for, there is no reason to have one duplicate for any possible combination you can create with date or DateTime.

Answer (score 2):

```
$olddate = "Thu, 14 Apr 2011 18:23:19 GMT";
$newdate = date("F d, Y H:i A",strtotime($oldDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it helps

```
echo(date('F j,Y g:i:A',strtotime(Date_From_RSS)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
echo (date('F j,Y g:i:A',strtotime($Yourinputdate)));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
// Assuming today is March 10th, 2001, 5:16:18 pm, and that we are in the
// Mountain Standard Time (MST) Time Zone

$today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");                 // March 10, 2001, 5:16 pm
$today = date("m.d.y");                         // 03.10.01
$today = date("j, n, Y");                       // 10, 3, 2001
$today = date("Ymd");                           // 20010310
$today = date('h-i-s, j-m-y, it is w Day');     // 05-16-18, 10-03-01, 1631 1618 6 Satpm01
$today = date('\i\t \i\s \t\h\e jS \d\a\y.');   // it is the 10th day.
$today = date("D M j G:i:s T Y");               // Sat Mar 10 17:16:18 MST 2001
$today = date('H:m:s \m \i\s\ \m\o\n\t\h');     // 17:03:18 m is month
$today = date("H:i:s");                         // 17:16:18
?>
```

above code taken from : http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

i didnot see you have an input so here it is:

```
$date = new DateTime('Thu, 14 Apr 2011 18:23:19 GMT');
echo $date->format("F j, Y g:i a");
```

Comment: The code above is [Example #4 date() Formatting](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.date.php). If you copy content from the web, make sure you A) are legally allowed to do so and B) cite the source. Please update your answer.

Comment: @Gordon well actually i did write the source. But i think i delete it while editing. Thanks for the warning